# 4 petal rose formula that fits astroid (pedal curve) in desmos

Tags: math, astroid

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g7m5l5zaxa

\left(\frac{6\sin\left(t\right)^{2}\cos\left(t\right)}{4\sin\left(t\right)^{2}+\cos^{2}\left(t\right)},\frac{3\sin\left(t\right)\cos^{2}\left(t\right)}{4\sin\left(t\right)^{2}+\cos\left(t\right)^{2}}\right)

I cannot fathom the quadrifolium formula (4 petal rose) that fits the astroid. Is it the pedal curve? I tried the pedal curve parametric equations but got a different result.

I tried the parametric equation from below link:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pedal_curve

Comment: Since StackOverflow is a community focusing on specific programming problems, please make the programming-related part of your math-focused question more obvious. People here for example usually expect a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? the equation of yours is in unsupported format rewrite it to be readable. How did you tried the equation? where is relevant code? What platform (OS/language/gfx lib) ...